# How to know the GSD (grid size, resolution) in meters of an existing raster when working in Geographic coordinates?

Tags: raster, resolution

I would need to know the GSD or grid size (resolution), in meters, of a raster created when working in a Geographic coordinate system in ArcGIS. Is is possible?

Even better, can I set the Cell size of the raster in meters (not in degree units) when I perform the raster creation if I am working in a Geographic coordinate system?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an exact value, this is simply not possible. Indeed, the size of a degree varies with the location, so you can't tell exactly the size of your pixel in meter based on a grid in degree. If you convert to a projected coordinate sytem, this grid will be distorted and you will need some kind of resampling.

For a quick estimate, you can consider that 1 degree of latitude = 111.3 km and one degree of longitude = 111.3 km* cos(latitude). See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/how-to-calculate-area-of-1-x-1-degree-cells-in-a-raster/29743#29743) for more details