# SQL Syntax to extract (convert) Strings with Degrees Minutes to Decimal Degrees

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with a two string fields containing Lat and Long coordinates in degrees and decimal minutes, like this `45° 24.5' N` `3° 43.01' E`.

How can I convert them into decimal degrees, for use in `ST_GeographyFromText`?

Comment: Maybe there is a contrary of this function: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html

Comment: I'm wondering if the [gps] tag is worth adding here, since GPS is one of the few modern use cases for DDMM.M?

Comment: And since there's no common tags linking a related Q, here it is: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29525/what-is-the-origin-of-the-degrees-decimal-minutes-format

Comment: @martinf I know that carrying the gps tag is not very nice but it's from the original data and I have to keep it in the database

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I didn't know "carrying the gps tag is not very nice". I'm not commenting on your DB -- just thought it might be a useful/relevant tag to add to this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this:

**[DMS2DD for PostGIS](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/115/dms2dd-for-postgis)**

---

**EDIT**

Presuming this is your *PostGIS* table,

[image]

running the **[DMS2DD](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/115/dms2dd-for-postgis)** function gives this:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Because you have only `Degrees and Minutes`,

[image]

in the **[DMS2DD](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/115/dms2dd-for-postgis)** function you need to ***comment one single line*** to achieve your results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info but I've already seen this function. The problem is that I've got Degrees Minutes (DM) and not Degrees Minutes Seconds (DMS) and therefore it does not work. The formula for calculation is easy: 45° 24.5' = 45° 24.5/60 = 45.4083 but I don't know how to split my string field to be able to calculate Decimal Degrees (DD)...

Comment: I've updated my response. You don't need to split the strig fields to be able to calculate only from `Degrees and Minutes`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there exists no function that is the inverse of [ST_AsLatLongText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html), but it is well [discussed](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2564). It would be a very useful function.

For your business:

When you are familiar with R than you can use this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404828), which converts your coordinates from degrees to decimals.

After that you update your table with the new coordinates (best way would be a [postgresql/postgis connection with R](https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/), see [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html) and [DBI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html)). And then you can use the ST_GeographyFromText function.